# Calling function at memory address x86_x64

Tags: x86-64, buffer-overflow

I'm writing some shellcode, and I would like to know how to properly call a function from assembly that resides in libc.Note that the address below is the address of the system function. I'm certain I've got this address correct, because if I overwrite the return address with this address, system is called successfully, but it seems to segfault within the assembly (which is contained in a buffer). If anything is unclear, let me know. I'm trying to get a libc function call working on a executable stack, andI'm pulling my hair out here. Note that the code reaches the buffer okay, and starts going through the appropriate nop sled, but segfaults on the call instruction (code below).

```
mov 0xf7ff7fa5b640, %rax
mov (hex representation of /bin/sh), %rdi
call *%rax
```

Comment: `mov 0xf7ff7fa5b640, %rax` does assemble (with current GAS) to a movabs load from that absolute address, `48 a1 40 b6 a5 7f ff f7 00 00   movabs rax,ds:0xf7ff7fa5b640` (disassembled in GNU intel-syntax).  I deleted my incorrect answer which guessed that you might be truncating the pointer to 32 bits by not using the `movabs` mnemonic.  Obviously the value you loaded is not a valid pointer to code, e.g. maybe its pointing to non-executable memory.  Use the debugger to check the value in `rax`, and that it points to valid memory.

Comment: Related: [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](//stackoverflow.com/q/19552158).